# Place ul li content side by side

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have some ul li content like the below image. This contents are coming vertically. But I would like to place them horizontally. How can I do that ??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your css code

```css
ul{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>Apple
<li>Iphone</li>
<li>Iphone 6s</li>
</ul>
<ul>Samsung
<li>Galaxy</li>
<li>galaxy s7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

**use this**

```
#ul_top_hypers li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display property to arrange the content of **ul** side by side. Follow the syntax below:-

```
.ul_content{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If it still not works, may be something is over writing it. So just add **!important** keyword after property value. i.e.,

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

I hope it works!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a float to each smartphone family like this:

```
#div_element{
         display: inline-block;
         float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one common div above the ui

html:

```
<body>

<div class="box">
<h4>Apple</h4>
<ul class="lists">
     <li>iPhone 6s Plus</li>
      <li>iPhone 6s </li>
       <li>iPhone 5s Plus</li>
        <li>iPhone 5s</li>
         <li>iPhone 6s Plus</li>
      <li>iPhone 6s </li>
       <li>iPhone 5s Plus</li>
        <li>iPhone 5s</li>
</ul>
</div><!--end of box-->

<div class="box">
<h4>Samsung</h4>
<ul class="lists">
     <li>Samsung Guru</li>
      <li>Samsung galaxy Y </li>
       <li>Samsung 6</li>
        <li>Samsung 7</li>
</ul>
</div><!--end of box-->


</body>
```

css:

```
.box{
        display: inline;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        margin: 10px;
    }
    h4{
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
   ul{
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }
   ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
   }
```